# How would I put a random player within a 300 block radius into a team

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am working on a murder mystery map for my minecraft server and I want to make it so one person in the lobby is randomly selected to join the murder scoreboard team, one randomly selected person to join the detective team, and the rest in another team.

Comment: Have you made any attempt to solve this yourself? Arqade works better when askers show effort to solve their own problems; we see that you have a problem you've worked on, and answerers respond to that. You also get a more specific answer that's tailored exactly to the part you're stuck, and Arqade gets a very specific question. Everybody wins!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume the "other" team is the innocents.
First, set everyone to the default (innocent) team, then use @r to set a random player to the detective team, then use @r[team=innocent] to select a random player from the innocent team and set their team to murderer.